# Decrypt RSA encrypted value generated from .net in Android

Tags: c#, android, .net, encryption, rsa

I have gone through many posts here but did not find the right solution. I want to decrypt a value encrypted in c# .net from Android.

I have successfully decrypted in .net platform using the following code snippet

```
public static void Main()
{
    string _privateKey = Base64Decode("myprivatekey");

     var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
       string data = "198,47,144,175,154,47,194,175,242,41,212,150,220,177,198,161,236,36,197,62,18,111,21,244,232,245,90,234,195,169,141,195,139,199,131,163,26,124,246,50,102,229,73,148,18,110,170,145,112,237,23,123,226,135,158,206,71,116,9,219,56,96,140,19,180,192,80,29,63,160,43,127,204,135,155,67,46,160,225,12,85,161,107,214,104,218,6,220,252,73,252,92,152,235,214,126,245,126,129,150,49,68,162,120,237,246,27,25,45,225,106,201,251,128,243,213,250,172,26,28,176,219,198,194,7,202,34,210";
        var dataArray = data.Split(new char[] { ',' });
        byte[] dataByte = new byte[dataArray.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.Length; i++)
        {
            dataByte[i] = Convert.ToByte(dataArray[i]);
        }

        rsa.FromXmlString(_privateKey);
        var decryptedByte = rsa.Decrypt(dataByte, false);
        Console.WriteLine(_encoder.GetString(decryptedByte));       
}
```

Now I want to do the same process in Android app. Please can somebody guide me through this?
I have tried the following code but its throwing `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: input must be under 128 bytes` exception

```
        String modulusString = "hm2oRCtP6usJKYpq7o1K20uUuL11j5xRrbV4FCQhn/JeXLT21laKK9901P69YUS3bLo64x8G1PkCfRtjbbZCIaa1Ci/BCQX8nF2kZVfrPyzcmeAkq4wsDthuZ+jPInknzUI3TQPAzdj6gim97E731i6WP0MHFqW6ODeQ6Dsp8pc=";
        String publicExponentString = "AQAB";

        byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.decode(modulusString, DEFAULT);
        byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.decode(publicExponentString, DEFAULT);
        BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);
        BigInteger publicExponent = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);

        RSAPrivateKeySpec rsaPubKey = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent);
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey pubKey = fact.generatePrivate(rsaPubKey);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

        byte[] plainBytes = result.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
        byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(plainBytes);
        String encryptedStringBase64 = Base64.decode(cipherData, DEFAULT).toString();
```

Comment: For a 1024 bits (=128 bytes) key, the ciphertext should have the same length. However, the ciphertext posted in the C# code is only 99 bytes long and also contains values that are not allowed for the `byte` type, e.g. 543 or 823. Since the C# code seems to run, please post consistent test data (private test key and ciphertext) that works together with the C# code.

Comment: Okay I posted the actual value. Can you tell me the online tool where I can test the values?

Comment: Without the private key no repro is possible! If it is a productive key, create a **test** key pair and the associated ciphertext and post both.

Comment: Web sites for testing decryption also depend on the private key format (PKCS#1, PKCS#8, ...).

Comment: I am using the default method provided by RSACryptoServiceProvider in .net. supported key sizes of 384 to 16384.  Beside basic functional, I haven't tried defining by own key exchange. The default uses SHA256 hash function.

Comment: The posted Java code doesn't make sense for decryption: You are trying to derive the private key from the public key, which of course doesn't work (or you really try to decrypt with the public key, which of course also doesn't work.). Also, you are using `cipher` in encryption mode (`Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE`). But without complete test data, I can't assist further.

Comment: @Topaco It looks more like a half arsed attempt to create an encryption routine from an encryption routine to me. viper, why are you using UTF-16LE? That way the input is generally double the size in bytes compared to UTF-8. RSA can only encrypt modulus size - 11 bytes for PKCS#1 (and you're better off using a larger key and modulus size - 19 bytes for sure). Also, look up "hybrid cryptosystem".