# Decrypt RSA encrypted value generated from .net in Android

Tags: encryption, android, rsa, .net

I have gone through many posts here but did not find the right solution. I want to decrypt a value encrypted in c# .net from Android.

I have successfully decrypted in .net platform using the following code snippet

```
public static void Main()
{
    string _privateKey = Base64Decode("myprivatekey");

     var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
       string data = "198,47,144,175,154,47,194,175,242,41,212,150,220,177,198,161,236,36,197,62,18,111,21,244,232,245,90,234,195,169,141,195,139,199,111,163,26,124,246,50,102,229,73,148,18,110,170,145,112,237,23,123,226,135,158,206,71,823,9,219,56,96,140,19,180,192,80,29,63,160,43,127,204,135,155,67,46,160,225,12,85,161,107,214,104,218,6,220,252,73,252,92,152,543,214,126,245,126,129";
        var dataArray = data.Split(new char[] { ',' });
        byte[] dataByte = new byte[dataArray.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.Length; i++)
        {
            dataByte[i] = Convert.ToByte(dataArray[i]);
        }

        rsa.FromXmlString(_privateKey);
        var decryptedByte = rsa.Decrypt(dataByte, false);
        Console.WriteLine(_encoder.GetString(decryptedByte));       
}
```

Now I want to do the same process in Android app. Please can somebody guide me through this?
I have tried the following code but its throwing `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: input must be under 128 bytes` exception

```
        String modulusString = "hm2oRCtP6usJKYpq7o1K20uUuL11j5xRrbV4FCQhn/JeXLT21laKK9901P69YUS3bLo64x8G1PkCfRtjbbZCIaa1Ci/BCQX8nF2kZVfrPyzcmeAkq4wsDthuZ+jPInknzUI3TQPAzdj6gim97E731i6WP0MHFqW6ODeQ6Dsp8pc=";
        String publicExponentString = "AQAB";

        byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.decode(modulusString, DEFAULT);
        byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.decode(publicExponentString, DEFAULT);
        BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);
        BigInteger publicExponent = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);

        RSAPrivateKeySpec rsaPubKey = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent);
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey pubKey = fact.generatePrivate(rsaPubKey);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

        byte[] plainBytes = result.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
        byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(plainBytes);
        String encryptedStringBase64 = Base64.decode(cipherData, DEFAULT).toString();
```

Comment: This looks more like a coding question (StackOverflow) than a security question (Security.SE). Also, your Java code appears to have... a lot of problems. Like, you're trying to create an RSAPrivateKeySpec but you're feeding it the public exponent? You're then trying to generate the private key from the public key? You're trying to use the resulting private key for initializing a cipher in encrypt mode (private keys can only decrypt or sign)? You're trying to use an encrypt-mode cipher to decrypt? Finally, don't try to use RSA as an ECB block cipher. Just. Don't. Use hybrid crypto instead.

Comment: Or did you accidentally post your Java code for encryption when you meant to post the decryption code? That doesn't resolve the thing where you're trying to use a private key for encryption, but it makes more sense than that all being a decrypt function. You still shouldn't ever try to encrypt more than one "block" of plaintext in RSA (in fact, the actual limit is lower, because you must leave room for padding). You should probably not be invoking these primitives at all for anything real, but if you must, use a [hybrid cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Comment: I am trying to decrypt. Mistakenly here I have set ENCRYPT_MODE

Comment: 1:1 identical with: [Decrypt RSA encrypted value generated from .net in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67430706/decrypt-rsa-encrypted-value-generated-from-net-in-android). Obviously cross posted on Information Security Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Topaco Dupe hammered it into submission.